# Testing Verify Method Call Without Argument In Test Class

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, java, junit, mock

I have a class which takes a message with payload String.
The payload is then split and used to create an Entity which is passed to DAOInterface to persist.

How can you test the call `daoInterface.insert(entity)` has been made?

To Mock the DAOInterface and then verify the call to DAO requires the entity in the test class which you dont have i.e.

```
verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);
```

Is this bad design i.e. creating the entity at this stage? Should the Sting[] split be passed to the DAOImplementaion and initialized there. Example problem,

```
public class ServiceClass {

    @AutoWire
    private DAOInterface daoInterface;

    public void serviceMessage(Message<String> message) {

        MessageHeaders mh = new MessageHeaders(message.getHeaders());       
        String[] split = ((String) mh.get("payload")).split("_");

        code omitted
        ...

        String type = mh.get("WhatType");

        Entity entity = new Entity(split[0], split[1], split[2]);

        if (type.equals("one"))
        {
            daoInterface.insert(entity); //How to verify this call?
        }
        else
        {
            if (type.equals("two"))
            {
                doaInterface.modify(entity); //How to verify this call?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can verify `daoInterface.insert` is called with `verify(daoInterface).insert(anyObject());`, but you have to mock DaoInterface first with `DaoInterface db = mock(DaoInterface.class);`. `verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);` will fail all the time because entity object from verify's argument and entity inside `serviceMessage()` are different instance. Instead, you can implement an entity matcher to make sure entity contents are match,

```
public class EntityMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Entity> {
    private Entity mEntity;

    public EntityMatcher(Entity entity) {
        mEntity = entity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        Entity entity = (Entity)argument;

        if (mEntity.equals(entity)) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

A working test example can be,

```
@Test
public void test() {
    DaoInterface db = mock(DaoInterface.class);

    ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass(db);
    service.serviceMessage("a_b_c");

    verify(db).insert(argThat(new EntityMatcher(
        new Entity("a", "b", "c")
    )));
}
```